# GoogleスプレッドシートにCF7から挿入した際のトリガーについての質問です。

Tags: google-apps-script

GoogleスプレッドシートにCF7 Google Sheet Connectorからデータを挿入した際に
シート1の一番下へ追加されますけれど、それをシート3へと逆順にしたいと思いまして、
以下のJavaScriptを書きました。

そこで、トリガーについてなのですけれど、
イベントのソースを選択：スプレッドシートから
イベントの種類を選択：編集時
としますと、CF7 Google Sheet Connectorからシート1に挿入されましてもGASは
動作しませんで、
イベントのソースを選択：スプレッドシートから
イベントの種類を選択：変更時
にしますと、シート3の行幅・列幅を変更しただけでもGASが動作してしまいます。
JavaScriptにて
if (sheet_add.getName() == "シート1") {
としてシート1がアクティブになったときだけGASを動かしたいのですが、シート3の
行幅・列幅でGASが動作してしまいます理由は何でしょうか？

```
// FormApp.getActiveForm()

function reverse() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();// Container Bound Script
    var sheet_add = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    if (sheet_add.getName() == "シート1") {

        // スプレッドシートを取得する
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];// シート1を指定して取得
        var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();

        var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 13);
        var currentRangeValues = range.getValues();

        var sheet3 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[2];// シート3を指定して取得

        var numRows = currentRangeValues.length;
        var numColumns = currentRangeValues[0].length;

        sheet3.insertRows(2,1);
        sheet3.getRange(2, 1, numRows, numColumns).setValues(currentRangeValues);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決？しました。
結局、同じスプレッドシートの別シートへのデータコピーではトリガーが起動してしまいますので、全く別のスプレッドシートへとデータをコピーしまして、コピー先のスプレッドシート上ではコピー元のスプレッドシートのトリガー無関係ですから、その場しのぎをしています。